# @semantic-release/git and protected branches

Tags: gitlab-ci, semantic-release

When using the `semantic-release` plugin `@semantic-release/git` on protected branch (master is protected with maintainers allowed to merge and no one allowed to push and merge)

I have

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project
```

I also tried with allowed to force push enabled but it changes nothing.

What's the solution ?

***EDIT***

If I unprotect the branch it is working.

The access token has all rights (I checked all boxes).

But I'm not sure that I can push something to a branch that has no one allowed to push and merge, even with any token.

I tried setting GITLAB_TOKEN with CI_JOB_TOKEN value.  But it is not working.  It tells me the token is invalid.

Comment: Came across this post: `https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/discussions/2557`- hope it's helpful.

Comment: It's about github and not gitlab pipeline

Comment: Did you try to create an ACCESS_TOKEN with a sufficient role/scope? If the bot (which is running the push call) has the needed rights it might work. Do you get it to work on not-protected branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When noone is allowed to push and merge, it means that only merge commits are allowed, and normal (direct) commits cannot be pushed.

Unfortunately, this is what the `@sematic-release/git` requires -- it is going to create a direct commit with an updated `package.json` and maybe other changes (changelog etc), and this direct commit will also be tagged with the version number the `@sematic-release` plugin generated.

Personally, I don't like this approach, and prefer to avoid extra commits that have no bearing on the code itself.

We didn't find a way to solve this without unprotecting the branches or at least allowing pushes. Eventually we migrated to custom versioning workflow which didn't need extra commits and used tags instead.

Comment: How are you managing changelog generation?

Comment: well, we don't =)

Comment: edit: pressed Enter too early

our product is a SaaS, so we're fine with semi-manual changelog based on Jira issues, mostly listing big features and client-facing fixes. we considered keeping the `@semantic-release` just for the changelog (devs liked that), but the inconveniences outweighted the (limited) benefits of a changelog. 

also, there are other tools for generating a changelog, e.g. [`git-cliff`](https://github.com/orhun/git-cliff)